# How does a Flux built from merges complete

Tags: project-reactor

If have the following

```
Flux<String> flux1 = ...
Flux<String> flux2 = ...
Flux<String> mergedFlux = flux1.merge(flux2);
```

How/When/Why will the mergedFlux complete?

The principle of least surprise would might suggest it will complete when any of the merged fluxes have completed. However, this is not what I have witnesses.

Answer (score 2):

The semantics of merge is to attempt to **exhaustively** replay the interleaved emissions of both `Flux` into a single `Flux`. As a consequence, the merged `Flux` only completes when **both** sources complete.

Contrast that with an operator like `zip` which aims at producing as many pairs as possible by taking one element from each source. As such it completes when any of the sources completes, because from then on it cannot produce pairs anymore.